# unable to process jar files while packing

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I'm developing `xamarin.forms` `PCL` application and after I installed `Xam.Plugin.Media` in `Visual Studio 2015` I encountered the following errors:

> Error     unable to process jar files while packaging
>   'C:\Users\wael\AppData\Local\Temp\atmd1fta.14n\resources.apk.bk'
>
> Error     unable to open
>   'obj\Debug__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations\library_project_imports\support-annotations.jar'
>   as a zip file: -40
>
> Error     packaging of
>   'C:\Users\wael\AppData\Local\Temp\atmd1fta.14n\resources.apk.bk'
>   failed    E:\Picker\Picker\Picker\Picker.Android\AAPT Picker.Android

Please help

Comment: Please include a full diagnostic build error log.

Comment: Thanx for reply. I already solved the problem, and it was compatibility issue. The  Xam.Plugin.Media depends on Permssion.Plugin and if it’s already installed then it will be upgraded automatically to the latest version which cause the problem. I just downgraded the Xam.Plugin.Media and it works fine.